# How to give an inverted nbt tag to a mob?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Im having a problem where I need to grab the downwards motion of a player and transfer it to an upwards motion for another entity, I know how to give the Y motion of a player to an entity with the /data command, but I do not how to inverse it. Plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `execute store` with scale to invert it by doing:

```
/execute store result entity <Target> Motion[1] double -1 run data get entity <Source> Motion[1]
```

We can also use scale inside the `data` command, but using it there makes the returning value an integer, making for example `0.9` be `-1.0`. We can avoid it by using the scale inside the `execute` command which let us choose the data type.